Re-use Terraform module using PAT token access : Failed to download module error
I am working on a Terraform project and I created a private repository for my WindowsVM module, the problem is I can't seem to be able to re-use this module in my deployment code . My deployment code resides in a seperate private repository on the same Azure DevOps project as my WindowsVM repo.
I am trying right now the PAT way, I have created a PAT on my Azure DevOps project.
Then I created a Git task on my YAML pipeline:

Here is the code of creation of my resource using my WindowsVM module :

The error my pipeline is displaying with this configuration:

Any idea why is this happening or what elements are missing in my configuration ?
All suggestions are welcome !

You need to fix the variable syntax to $(PATToken), and simply add extra header. please check the reply below for the details, let me know if you have any queries.

Please fix the variable syntax ${PATToken} as $(PATToken). And you can simply set extra header with below command:
git config --global url."https://$(token)@dev.azure.com".insteadOf "https://yourorgname@dev.azure.com"

My yaml for your reference:
- task: TerraformInstaller@1
  inputs:
    terraformVersion: 'latest'

- script: |
    git config --global url."https://$(token)@dev.azure.com".insteadOf "https://testorg@dev.azure.com"
  displayName: 'set extra header'

- powershell: |  
    terraform init -upgrade

My tf file:



hello @wade , thank you for your suggestion, i followed your steps on my end but i got the same error even with these changes. I'm confused as to the reason this has happened

Please confirm the account has permission on the repo and generate a new token. In addition, on the DevOps repo, click clone at the top right, copy the https url and paste it in the terraform module for repo link. You can find the details from my above screenshot. If the issue persists, please update your configuration so we can have a check. thanks.
